# Porting a C/C++ program into Android

Tags: android, cross-platform, shared-libraries, native, android-ndk

I am attempting to put my C++ program onto an Android phone but have run into several problems with the library linking. It seems most of the useful information I find on this topic through google is outdated ([motz](http://honeypod.blogspot.com/2007/12/shared-library-hello-world-for-android.html)) or simply does not account for the complexity of my program. I have been able to run simple C programs but fail when attempting to use libraries outside of Android's Bionic/libc.

So my questions are:

- Is it possible to port pre-existing *.so libraries onto Android? If so, how could I do this without seg faulting?
- Should I be using the CodeSourcery compiler (arm-none-linux-gnueabi-*)?
- How can I work around the lack of a seperate pthread library?

Please help me out! Thanks.

-Scott

Answer (score 2):

You can't use pre-existing *.so files because they need to be compiled for Android.  In order to create an *.so for Android you need to use their NDK, which is already set up to build the correct format so you don't need to worry about arm-none-linux-gnueabi or anything.  If you want to use a library that isn't available on Android you'll need to build it yourself using the NDK.  I had to do this with the STL.

Comment: Thank you. I am in the process of creating Android.mk files for the libraries to allow them to compile with the source code (I have several libraries to include). For anyone interested, there is a good tutorial on Android.mk files at http://androidcore.com/ which is helping me get by.

Comment: surprisingly, i am doing the same right now :)
another nice article is http://www.datasprings.com/Resources/ArticlesInformation/AndroidSDKExampleApplicationSampleCode/tabid/910/currentpage/6/Default.aspx

if/when you find the way to debug C code, let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the following :

[Can i use the native libraries (installed in android stack) in my NDK application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169336/can-i-use-the-native-libraries-installed-in-android-stack-in-my-ndk-applicatio/10169880#10169880)

This should answer you some queries...