# How to Write Permission to System/app in Android

Tags: android

how to give write `permission` to `system/app` folder 
i have rooted my android device
i want to download the app and install in `system/app` folder

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "su" );
```

i had tried this command it ask for user `permission` and then it throws exception 
`system/app` is read only file system

Comment: The file system must be remounted with write permissions.

Answer (score 9):

First go to shell using

```
adb shell
```

Then remount the system folder as writable using following commands

```
$ su
# mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
```

Then change the permission of system folder to Read, Write and Execute using

```
# chmod 777 /system/app
```

Comment: Should I change the permissions back to 755 after I do this?

Comment: No need once your process that changed the permission gets killed, your permissions will be reset to read-only.

Answer (score 3):

Just type in your android device terminal

```
       su
```

and then

```
       chmod 777 system/app
```

***su***- grants you superuser permission

and  ***chmod 777***  file, change the permissions of the file to read, write, and execute..

Comment: @drdrej that's because you aren't rooted. You need root to install anything in the /system partition on standard devices.

Answer (score 1):

Try `adb remount` in terminal.
If you want to do it from the device shell, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294808/android-mount-the-filesystem-with-write-permission) on how to remount the file system with write permission.