# Adb Shell: when I run mount rw /system the smartphone reboots

Tags: android, shell, adb, mount

My problem regards the mount of the /system directory of Android, particularly when I try to do it with my Sony Xperia L.

I try to use this command after get su permission

```
mount -o remount,rw /system
```

initially it seems to work but after few second the phone reboots.
The same command on Nexus 5 works.

I try also these commands that I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294808/android-mount-the-filesystem-with-write-permission) but the result is the same:

```
mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mmcblk0p9 /system
mount -o rw,remount -t ext4 /system
```

The phone is rooted and I get su permission before make it.